# C-pseudo code to assembly

Tags: c, assembly

My boss asked me to convert this to assembly and I don't know a lot about assembly. Could someone please help me out?

This is the C-pseudo code given to me

```
 //Global Variables 
 #define HRM_PERIOD 15

int hrArr [HRM_PERIOD]

int *hrPt = hrArr;

/* 
Function addtoarray
Parameter: int np - a value to add to the array

Description: Stores 16-bit value np in array using global pointer hraPt.
 hraPt is incremented so that the next call will add the value
 to the next element in the array. The pointer wraps to start
 when it reaches the end of the array
*/ 

void addToArray(int np)
{
*hraPt = np;// save value
hraPt++; // increment pointer
// wrap around
if (hraPt == hrArr + HRM_PERIOD) 
hraPt = hrArr
}
```

Please help me

Comment: For what architecture and processor?

Comment: Not to sound too snarky, but your boss seems to have problems assigning tasks to resources effectively.  If the company needs assembly development done, they may want to hire an assembly developer.

Comment: Is your "boss" a college professor, by any chance?

Comment: Couldn't you do that with the compiler? That's basically what they do, and they generally do it better than we do anyway. Why is your boss asking you to do this? This looks more like homework than work.

Comment: Damn. I'd just written it in MOS-6502 assembly, and the question got closed. :-(

Comment: @BRPocock: Oooh, that sound fun. I might have to give it a try. 8v)

Comment: LOL @ WTP 

Gmail is the best bro

Answer (score 7):

Can you try the -S option of the GCC ?

[This](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.2//gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options) is the documentation

-S option:

*"Stop after the stage of compilation proper; do not assemble. The output is in the form of an assembler code file for each non-assembler input file specified.
 By default, the assembler file name for a source file is made by replacing the suffix '.c', '.i', etc., with '.s'.
 Input files that don't require compilation are ignored."*

I believe that if you put that code in a file "source.c", and you have gcc installed this will do the work:

```
gcc -S source.c
```

The output will be a file named: source.s -> the assembly code.

Comment: Better yet, tell your boss to check the `-S` option.